# pass URI.parseQuery value from default funtion to a user defined funtion

Tags: reactjs

I want to access user id and date from the url to function but because this is not the default class

http://localhost:3000/update?user=66&date=2022-06-27&tab=user

```
const getuserData = (props) => {
  
  console.log(props.user);
 console.log(props.date);
 
};
```

i have used  useLocation

```
const Tracker = (props) => {
  const search = useLocation().search;

 console.log(URI.parseQuery(search));
```

`console.log(URI.parseQuery(search))`  is returning in cosole the following  `{user: '66', date: '2022-06-28', tab: 'diet'}`

i want to pass `user` & `date` into  `getuserData`

full code i have given in sandbox for refernce https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-lalande-87jbpq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Theres no getUserData in your demo, also it has an error : `Could not find module in path: './add_symptom' relative to '/src/App.js'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and read [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for more info.

```js
const getuserData = ({
  user,
  date
}) => {

  console.log(user);
  console.log(date);

};


const {
  search
} = useLocation();

getuserData(URI.parseQuery(search))
```

Comment: but how to pass

Comment: what changes must i make in  const Tracker & const getuserData

Comment: i tryed ur new answer still its giving un defined pls check the codesand box so u know how i have coded

Comment: @jisaks your code does not work.

Comment: no it doesnot becacuse its part of a very big project its imposbile to make a sandbox of the entire code

Comment: my question is simple i just want to pass  user & date to getuserData

Comment: Cound you do (console.log(search)) in Tracker? See if search has user & date.

Comment: when i do `console.log(search))`  i am getting `?user=66&date=2022-06-28&tab=diet`

Comment: when i do  `console.log(URI.parseQuery(search));`   iam getting `{user: '66', date: '2022-06-28', tab: 'diet'}`

Comment: Instead of `getuserData(search)` use ` getuserData(URI.parseQuery(search))` @jisaks